# Getting variables from a text file and process mulitple database restores

Tags: c#, sql, queue, text-files, database-restore

I have a C# webform application that needs to read database name variables from a text file and process a restore. I want the application to restore the databases one by one because the process is sensitive. The text file could have up to 10 databases to restore in one night. What is the best way to read through the database name variables individually and process the restore for each? I have a significant amount of code for the restore, so i'd like to run my application once for one database, then again for another database, then again for another database ,etc, etc. I don't need my code to run fast as I have hours to complete the restores.

variables in text file look something like this:

```
dbName:"dbName"
ServerToRestoreTo:"Server/instance"

dbName:"dbName2"
ServerToRestoreTo:"Server/instance2"

...
...
...
... up to 10 dbName and ServerToRestoreTo
```

Also, I am still working on the structure of the text file, so I am open to suggestions with that part of it.

Comment: I added a very long answer, but hopefully it will help out here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it: maintain a separate file to keep track of the databases that you've already restored. Then just pick the first database from the master list that doesn't have an entry in the 'RestoredDatabases.txt' file.

**UPDATE**

I've created a class to store the database information from a text file, and a method that can be called that will populate a list of this class from your file structure.

First, here's a class to represent a database that can be read from or written to a file. **Note:** I overrode the `ToString()` method so it writes text in the same file structure that you mentioned, and I implemented `Equals` to allow easy comparison between lists of this object.

```
private class LogFileDatabase
{
    public const string NamePrefix = "dbName:";
    public const string ServerPrefix = "ServerToRestoreTo:";

    public string DbName { get; set; }
    public string Server { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}\"{1}\"{2}{3}\"{4}\"",
            NamePrefix, DbName, Environment.NewLine, ServerPrefix, Server);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((LogFileDatabase) obj);
    }

    private bool Equals(LogFileDatabase other)
    {
        return (string.Equals(DbName, other.DbName) && 
            string.Equals(Server, other.Server));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return ((DbName != null ? DbName.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397) ^
                    (Server != null ? Server.GetHashCode() : 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Next, I wrote a method that will read a text file, parse it for database and server names, and return a list of the above `LogFileDatabase` objects:

```
private static IEnumerable<LogFileDatabase> GetDatabasesFromLog(string logPath)
{
    if (logPath == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("logPath");

    if (!File.Exists(logPath))
    {
        throw new FileNotFoundException(
            string.Format("logPath does not exist: {0}", logPath));
    }

    var databasesFromLog = new List<LogFileDatabase>();

    var fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(logPath)
        .Where(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line));

    var logFileDb = new LogFileDatabase();

    foreach (var fileLine in fileLines)
    {
        var dbNameIndex = fileLine.IndexOf(LogFileDatabase.NamePrefix);
        if (dbNameIndex > -1)
        {
            logFileDb.DbName = fileLine.Substring(
                dbNameIndex + LogFileDatabase.NamePrefix.Length).Replace("\"", "");

            continue;
        }

        var serverIndex = fileLine.IndexOf(LogFileDatabase.ServerPrefix);
        if (serverIndex == -1) continue;

        logFileDb.Server = fileLine.Substring(
            serverIndex + LogFileDatabase.ServerPrefix.Length).Replace("\"", "");

        databasesFromLog.Add(logFileDb);
        logFileDb = new LogFileDatabase();
    }

    return databasesFromLog;
}
```

Finally, here is an example of how to use the class and method to read the database file and restore the first database that doesn't exist in the restored databases file, and then writes the name of the restored database to the new file:

```
public static void Main()
{
    // The file containing all databases to restore
    string databasesToRestore = "c:\\program\\settings\\DatabasesToRestore.txt";

    // A file that will contain the names of databases that have already been restored
    string restoredDatabases = "c:\\program\\workingDir\\RestoredDatabases.txt";

    if (File.Exists(databasesToRestore))
    {
        // Ensure restored databases file exists
        if (!File.Exists(restoredDatabases)) 
        { using (var tmp = File.Create(restoredDatabases)) { } }

        LogFileDatabase databaseToRestore =
            GetDatabasesFromLog(databasesToRestore)
                .Except(GetDatabasesFromLog(restoredDatabases))
                .FirstOrDefault();

        if (databaseToRestore != null)
        {
            // Call retore database code here, restoring `databaseToRestore`
            RestoreDbToServer(databaseToRestore.DbName, databaseToRestore.Server);

            // Write the name of the database we just restored 
            // to our 'restoredDatabases` file       
            File.AppendAllLines(restoredDatabases,
                new List<string> {databaseToRestore.ToString()});
        }
        else
        {
            // There are no databases left to restore, 
            // so we can delete our `restoredDatabases` file now.
            // But be careful - this means when you run the program again, 
            // it will start restoring the first database.
            File.Delete(restoredDatabases);
        }
    }
}
```